# Is the product $AB$ invertible if $A$ is invertible and $B$ is non-invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, inverse

$A$ is an invertible matrix and $B$ is a non-invertible matrix. Can $AB$ be invertible?
I have the following idea:

Sup. $AB$ is invertible, then:

$B=IB=(A^{-1}A)B=A^-1(AB)$, then apply inverse both sides:

$B^{-1}=(AB)^{-1}(A^{-1})^{-1}=(AB)^{-1}A$, but $B$ is non-invertible (hip). This leads to a contradiction, as we supposed $AB$ is invertible.

Therefore $AB$ is non-invertible.

I'm not sure if the step where I apply "inverse both sides" is right. Otherwise I'm not sure how to prove this.

Note 1: I CAN'T use $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$ since the hypothesis for that theorem is $A, B$ invertible matrices and this is not the case.

Note 2: I CAN'T use determinants yet.

Comment: A product of invertible matrices is invertible.

Comment: If $A$ is invertible and $B$ is not, then $AB$ is not invertible.

Comment: Can you use $\det AB=\det A\det B$?

Comment: @Jakobian Yes, but the contrapositive of that statement isn't this one I think.

Comment: @JMoravitz That's what I want to prove.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I forgot to mention I can't use determinants yet.

Comment: Refer to the [invertible matrix theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html) which gives a *long* list of equivalent conditions for a matrix to be considered invertible.  You should have seen at least some of these proven before.  It may be easiest to use a specific one of these, be it related to determinants, or related to nullspaces or injectivity, or what have you.

Comment: @FabrizioGambelín you can use what I said to show, in a very simple way, that $B$ must be invertible if $A$ and $AB$ are

Comment: @JMoravitz I still cannot use determinants or nullspaces, thank you btw, might be useful later!

Comment: @Jakobian Oh, I see. That's because if the product is not invertible, then the matrices aren't invertible? (contrapositive of what you said)

Comment: "*can't use nullspaces*" I find this surprising.  One of the very first things I learned when I first took linear algebra was square matrix $A$ is invertible iff $\text{null}(A)=\{0\}$.  In any case, you should expect to prove or have proven most of those equivalences of conditions either through homework or in class.  Depending on your mindset and/or how you are taught, you'll find certain forms are more convenient.  As you progress through proving the entirety of the invertible matrix theorem, you'll have the option then to freely switch between definitions of being invertible.

Comment: @JMoravitz yeah, it comes in the next chapter.

Comment: You should say that these are square matrices of the same size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument is correct, though depending on the level, you may want to explain why
$$B^{-1}=\big(A^{-1}(AB)\big)^{-1}=(AB)^{-1}(A^{-1})^{-1}.$$
Another approach would be to suppose that $AB$ is invertible with inverse $C$.Then
$$(CA)B=C(AB)=I,$$
so $CA$ is the inverse of $B$, a contradiction.

Alternatively, you could note that if $B$ is non-invertible, then there exists some nonzero vector $x$ such that $Bx=0$. Then also $ABx=0$, and so $AB$ is non-invertible.

Comment: Seems good. However, I can't clearly see why is Bx=0 then ABx=0 also has a nonzero vector :/

Comment: Oh it was trivial! I'm a bit sleepy sorry, thank you very much for your help :)